# Genexus: System is out of resources al hacer Build With This Only a un objeto GeneXus

Tags: java, genexus, build, genexusxev3

Se intenta hacer build with this only a un objeto Genexus y no termina el build, arrojando error 
**The system is out of resources. 
Consult the following stack trace for details.** 
**java.lang.StackOverflowError**

Se utiliza generador Java. Ya probé agregando las opciones -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx8192m al compilador y sin ellas.

Versión Gx: **GeneXus X Evolution 3 - 10.3.101388 - Upgrade 8**.

Adjunto descripción completa del error:

```
Default (Java Web) Generation Success
Compressing static files...Success
========== HLogin Compilation for Default (Java Web) started ==========
callmake.bat "D:\ProyectosGx\GeneXus\JavaModel\web\GXJMake.exe" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\javac.exe" hlogin  options: -O -encoding iso-8859-1 -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx8192m
GeneXus Java Make v1.0

The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.readToken(JavaTokenizer.java:566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.nextToken(Scanner.java:115)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.nextToken(JavacParser.java:301)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.literal(JavacParser.java:759)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.literal(JavacParser.java:659)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1196)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:880)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:836)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:816)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseExpression(JavacParser.java:779)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1818)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1833)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1294)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:880)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:836)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.termRest(JavacParser.java:850)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:839)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:816)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2431)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:2337)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2308)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2322)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2480)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2484)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)

...

    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2488)

objetogx_impl.java:7376: error: reached end of file while parsing
         GxWebStd.gx_bitmap( httpContext, imgBt
                                               ^
```

1 error
failed ( error code=1)

Build failed.
HLogin Compilation for Default (Java Web) Failed
Build With This Only Failed

Comment: Será que quedó mal generado el archivo "objetogx" ? 
Intentaría modificar el objeto y hacer un build. El error es por el Stack Size de la JVM, no por la memoria

Comment: Gracias @GonzaloGallotti . Quité las opciones Xms/Xmx del java compiler, luego probé agregando la opción -J-Xss4m para stack size según observé en varios foros y por ahora no he tenido problemas nuevamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, lo he solucionado agregando la siguiente opción al compilador Java para setear el Stack Size de la jvm en 4MB: **-J-Xss4m**

En: Preferences -> Generator -> Java -> Build Process -> Advanced -> Compiler Options

He probado con "Force Generation" y también con "check" en Tools -> Options -> Build -> Build with this only y por ahora no he vuelto a tener problemas.